# New Class Giving Incorrect Return

Tags: powershell, class, object

I'm learning about objects and classes and following along with code on another site. It creates a new class `Student` that takes in `firstName`, `lastName`, `score`, and multiple variables for the birthday.

```
class Student {
    [string]$firstName = ""
    [string]$lastName = ""
    [int]$score = 3
    [System.DateTime]$birthday
    Student ([string]$firstName, [string]$lastName, [int]$score, [int]$day, [int]$month, [int]$year) {
        $this.firstName = $firstName
        $this.lastName = $lastName
        $this.score = $score
        $this.birthday = (Get-Date -minute 0 -second 0 -millisecond 0 -hour 0 -year $year -Day)
    }

    Student ([string]$firstName, [string]$lastName, [int]$score, [int]$day, [int]$month) {
        $this.firstName = $firstName
        $this.lastName = $firstName
        $this.score = $score
        $this.birthday = (Get-Date -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0 -Hour 0 -Year 2003 -Day $day -Month $month)
    }

    [string] GetFullName() {
        return ("{0} {1}" -f $this.firstName, $this.lastName)
    }

    [string] GetReportLine() {
        return ("{0} {1}" -f $this.firstName, $this.lastName)
    }

}
```

As I said, I'm learning, but I thought the `GetReportLine()` would display the first name and last name. However, when I create a new Student object

```
[Student]::new

$some = [Student]::new("Some", "Guy", 3, 2, 2)
```

and then tried calling it, writing all the code exactly as shown online, I get this as the output

```
$some.GetReportLine()
```

> Some Some

when I was expecting this as the output

> Some Guy

So, I've concluded either there's an error in the code or I'm just not understanding how the code works correctly.

Could you all check and let me know which it is? I'm just trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only IDEs could catch this kind of mistake, which happens to me wayyyyy too often. Your code works as written...lastname = $firstName.

```
class Student 
{
    Student ([string]$firstName, [string]$lastName, [int]$score, [int]$day, [int]$month) {
        $this.firstName = $firstName
        # ↓↓↓↓ ☢⚡⚠ !This is your problem! ☢⚡⚠
        $this.lastName = $firstName
    }
}
```

Comment: Good sleuthing, but given that the question warrants the closure reason "not reproducible or was caused by a typo", I think your answer would  have been better _as a comment_, along with a vote to close.

Comment: Oh my god, you’re right. Code is lovely when the errors are a bit more obvious. Thank you. It makes complete sense why it did that now.